# I'm trying to save an image, then load it to the view

Tags: android, image, save

This is my first question, so sorry for any mistakes :)

1.So when the user presses my button, it opens the gallery.<-(that works)

2.Then they select the image and it displays the image on the activity.<-(that also works)

3.Then when they come back to the app, the picture should be there.<-(THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESN'T WORK)

Here is the code for the page where everything happens(picking the image and saving it, then retrieving it):

Thanks for the help!

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE_A = 1;
    public static int imageId;
    static String imageSrcPick = "";
    ImageView pic;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    ImageView imageView;
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;
    private int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loadSavedPreferences();

        Button BtnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChooseImage);
        BtnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE_A);
            }
        });

        pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgPick);

        if (imageSrcPick.equals("")) {
            pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.main);

        } else {

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageSrcPick);
            pic.setImageBitmap(image);
        }
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    protected void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        String pick = sharedPreferences.getString("pick", "");
        imageSrcPick = pick;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE_A:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaColumns.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgPick);

                    MainActivity.imageSrcPick = picturePath;

                    savePreferences("pick", picturePath);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

`
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFB5C5"
    tools:context="com.Me.MyApp.MainActivity">

//this is the image that changes
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/ImgPick"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/myimage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

//this button is pressed to open the gallery and select the image
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="#CD2990"
        android:onClick="choose"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Choose Image"
        android:id="@+id/btnChooseImage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ImgPick"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="To save, quit the app and come back :)"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnChooseImage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can show your xml code

Comment: Between 2. and 3. the user closes your app? You did not say as much. Also you did not tell why you suppose the image would automatically be displayed then. Please tell how your code works before we have a look in your code. Put all info in your post.

Comment: @greenapps. Yes the user closes the app then reopens it, sorry for the omit.

Comment: @jiteshmohite. I just posted the XML. Again, sorry for the omit.

Comment: If you were really sorry you would have edited your post also. And you would have explained your code as asked. I wonder why you did not.

Answer (score 0):

Try that code in your switch case:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
try {
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgPick);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```